# How do I access HighCharts themes, modify and create new themes?

Tags: r, highcharts

I am using the R HighCharter package for some basic repetitive charting and I really find the default themes useful. However, I consistently need to modify a few of the settings (for example axis font size) due to screen resolution. What I'd like to do is to open the default themes and all that it entails, edit a few settings and save as a new theme so that it can be easily referenced with each chart creation. Is this easily doable within R? Otherwise, is the javascript for the theme accessible to me somewhere in the R download folder?

Example Code to display an hchart with a default theme that I would like to edit.

```
temp <- data.frame('xvals'=as.numeric(1:10),'yvals'=as.numeric(21:30),'MyGroup'=as.character(c('G1','G1','G1','G1','G1','G2','G2','G2','G2','G2')))
hchart(temp,'line',hcaes(x=xvals,y=yvals)) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_darkunica())
```

Comment: Did the below answer solve your problem? If so can you please mark it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to change the theme or for that matter any aspect of a highchart in R. I found [this](https://dantonnoriega.github.io/ultinomics.org/post/2017-04-05-highcharter-explainer.html) to be very useful. Default themes are available [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/themes/dark-unica.js) for you to see which parameter you'd like to change.

As an example, here's how you can change the color of the x axis labels.

```
library(highcharter)
temp <- data.frame('xvals'=as.numeric(1:10),'yvals'=as.numeric(21:30),'MyGroup'=as.character(c('G1','G1','G1','G1','G1','G2','G2','G2','G2','G2')))
hchart(temp,'line',hcaes(x=xvals,y=yvals)) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_darkunica()) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(
    labels = list(
      style = list(
        color = "#1DEBE4"
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am familiar with how to change the color of the labels, but I'd like (using your example) permanently change the color of the labels to the darkunica theme, or create my own theme modifying these labels as such.

Comment: You can use the `hc_theme()` function to create your own theme. Have a look at `?hc_theme`. You can compare from the attributes of `darkunica` (the link I provided above) and alter whatever you want to.

Comment: I'm looking at this documentation and I'm still not sure how this would create for me a permanent theme or allow me to modify an existing theme. I see that it would allow me to a temporary theme but I'm looking to create something that can be referenced every time I reference the package.

Comment: @user11058887 Dhiraj answer is correct. You can use hc_theme() function to create your own theme or you can edit the chart's look in the options - like in the example above. You can also merge theme with additional options as it's written in the documentation here at the very bottom of this page: http://jkunst.com/highcharter/themes.html

If you want to change the look of themes in the core, you should contact Highcharter creator and ask him about how to do it.

Comment: Thanks all for your assistance. I believe I have what I need. Just more cumbersome that I had originally anticipated.